# Visual Studio Team Services - cURLUploader to scp output from Publish Build Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to use the use the "Publish Build Artifacts" (artifact type "server") task to zip up my build output and then `scp` the zip file using cURLUploader to my deployment host.

I can't seem to figure out how to get a path to the zip file to enter into cURLUploader. Is there a better way to zip the build output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [Zip and unzip directory build task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-Zip) and use it to zip your build output. The Zip file will be generated in the same path as the folder you want to Zip.

> A set of Build tasks for TFS 2015 and Visual Studio Team Services that
>   enables you to Zip and Unzip a directories.